# I had a western digital nas but it has died. How can I get the contents off of it?

Tags: nas

I had a western digital bookworld nas.  It has died.  How can I get the contents off of it?  Thanks.

Comment: Lots of ways. You could research the question yourself and let us know what you've tried, what didn't work, the format of the hard drive...

Comment: Depends on the material you have. If you have a SATA connector, open the case and connect the drives to your computer.

Comment: When you say the hard drive "Died" do you mean its not spinning? go to Computer Disk Management by right-click "My Computer" and Select "Manage" and selecting "Disk Management" Once there, does the computer recognize the Hard Drive?

Comment: Please tell us more. What exactly have you noticed to say that it has died? Does it just not show up anymore? Did you hear (or can you hear) any different sounds coming from it when it's powered? There can be a problem with the enclosure or network hardware, or there can be a problem with the disk.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to open the unit.  There will be a normal hard drive inside.  Hopefully it is the unit and not the hard drive that died.  You can purchase a SATA to USB adapter and use it to connect the hard drive to your computer to see if it working.